# How to set and get sessionid from Django without web browser

Tags: django, django-views, django-sessions, django-1.6

I'm using Django 1.6.

I want to set session id.
When I use web browser, I can watch `"sessionid"` logs.

But, when I used other application like `Unity3d`,
I can't watch `"sessionid"` logs.

*Could you tell me how to get a session id?*

I've create the view

But, I'm accessing application like unity

it returns.

```
def get_token(request):
    # request_cookies = OrderedDict(request.COOKIES)
    context = {}
    context.update(csrf(request))

    context['csrf_token'] = force_text(context['csrf_token'])
    session_key = request.session.session_key
    context['sessionid'] = session_key

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), content_type="application/json")
```

But, session id is null. however web broweser is okey.

```
jsonText: {"csrf_token": "xma9Dtmv46va5uomZiZ9dcjjfCB9E2Gw", "sessionid": null}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are set using cookies. Cookies are implemented by the vast majority of browser but not by other http clients.

Since you mention Unity, I guess what you are building with Django is an api. I suggest you take a look at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication as an alternative to relying on cookies.